# how to change html content for colspan via coding

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose there is a case as below

```
      <tr> 
            <th>2012
            </th>
            <th colspan="3">
            2013                                 ---------1
            </th>
            <th>2012
            </th>
            <th colspan="3">2013
            </th>
        </tr>

2012 |        2013           |2012  |          2013        |----->2
```

So I want to convert it with C# coding like

```
 2012 | 2013  | **2013  | 2013**  |2012  | 2013  | **2013  | 2013**  |----->3
```

In my code I have on string which  contains 1

Is it possible to change the html content by "2" to "3" i.e I want the add the columm as specified in colspan (3-1 =2)

Comment: if you are not using asp.net and its just an html file read the file and replace what ever you want, if its in asp.net keep changing part in server control by adding runat="server" and you can change all inside it directly by referring the id of control.

Comment: The case is that I have a string which contains HTML content. There is one regex which match the colspan column form the string(html content).Based on colspan values I want to add the column in the table at a specific row via coding. Is this possible? So that I can get specific numbers of column.